# How to use IDA environment to run python scripts?

Tags: ida, idapython

I am trying out following technique:

https://github.com/CMUSTRUDEL/DIRTY

This is a deep learning approach for type and name recovery. It uses ida scripts to generate and preprocess the dataset.

It first requires me use IDA to generate the dataset.

```
python3 generate.py --ida /path/to/idat64 -b BINARIES_DIR -o OUTPUT_DIR_Step1
```

This extracts function information from the dataset. After that, I have to run preprocessing scripts as follows (the instruction on their GitHub are incomplete).

```
# Inside the dirty directory.

python -m utils.preprocess OUTPUT_PATH PATH_TO_DATASET_FILENAMES OUTPUT_DIR_Step1
```

But, the problem is that, the scripts don't take IDA path and they use `idapython` libraries such as `ida_typeinf`

Check - https://github.com/CMUSTRUDEL/DIRTY/blob/main/binary/dire_types.py

However, if I run the above python script, as it lies outside the ida environment, gives me lib not found errors (because it can't see `ida_typeinf`).

Is there any way to run this script within ida environment (that's what I believe is the issue, but I could be wrong). It is also possible that the above command `python -m utils.preprocess OUTPUT_PATH PATH_TO_DATASET_FILENAMES OUTPUT_DIR_Step1` may not be accurate and I need Ida command line to run that command. Note that I know how to run idat on individual binaries.

Comment: The scripts don't take IDA path as it contains them in `idastubs` directory (not sure if this is a copy or just a similar re-implementation).

Comment: you can find the Python libs at `<your IDA root dir>/python`

Comment: @Robert and mimak I tired to add both of them and set the PYTHONPATH, but no luck.

Comment: Are you looking for the -S parameter as in https://hex-rays.com/blog/igor-tip-of-the-week-08-batch-mode-under-the-hood/ (or to be more verbose https://hex-rays.com/blog/running-scripts-from-the-command-line-with-idascript/)? Afaik, those libraries are meant to be used from inside since they're calling into the disassembler/decompiler API. Hence, it's sorta weird to run the python interpreter to use them directly.

You can run scripts from the UI with Alt+F7 (File -> Script File), or use the -S parameter from the commandline to explicitly run a script in IDA once it has loaded the database.